# Change the entire row color based on different values in the Turn around time column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have Turn around time column with the constant numbers which will never change and a second column is the result with different numbers. My query is whether we can highlight amber, green, yellow color for the entire row if the result value is less or more than the Turn around time value. For example:-

> If Turn around time is 10, 11, 18 and in the second column value is below 10, 9, 15 or equal to 10, 11, 18 the row color is green
>
> If the second column is 15, 16, 23 that is more than the Turn around time 10, 11, 18 then the row color should be yellow color
>
> If the second column is 20, 21, 28 that is 10 times more than the Turn around time then the entire row color should be amber or red color

The columns are as mentioned below :-

[image]

Please confirm whether we can solve this query with formula or VBA code?

To make it very clear i have included one more screen shot example in the query, please confirm if we can compare negative values to a TAT value and then color the row.

In the below image if you see the 4th row the TAT value is 20 the result value is -30, if i compare the value 30 to the TAT 20, 30 is greater than 20 but since it is having negative value it is not coloring the rows perfectly, could you please confirm how to take tackle this type of problems in conditional formatting

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not VBA, you need conditional formatting.
Which excel version are you using? The following applies to 2007 and up.

Select your whole table, beginning with the first row of data. Make sure to select whole rows. Make sure your active cell is A2! (I'm assuming TAT is column A, and your table starts in row 1. If not, change the formula accordingly.)

Go to conditional formatting, select "New Rule". Pick "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".
In the "Format values where..." box, put this formula:

=$B2<=$A2

Change the Format to green cell colour.

Do the same with your other conditions: =$B2>$A2, cell colour yellow, =$B2>=($A2+10), cell colour red. The order of rules does matter.

Hope this helps, though you should read up on conditional formattings. Chandoo is a good place to start:
http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/03/13/excel-conditional-formatting-basics/

Comment: "=$B2>=($A2+10), cell colour red. The order of rules does matter." This part solves that. I assumed 10 times more actually meant more by at least 10, based on the example.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but look at his numbers: 10,11,18 and 20, 21, 28. Well, guess lifeinvba can figure it out from here anyway. :)

Comment: @vacip thanks for taking time to help me in the query, your solution worked for me, however I have edited the question and I have made it clear  to you what is my exact query, please look at the second image and confirm how to color the rows if there is negative result value when compared with TAT..thank you

Comment: @vacip I got the solution thanks for your help and also for pnuts helping me in this...